# Partial differential equations involving Feynman-Kac

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-integrals

I am working on solving the following pde on $[0,T]$;

$$f_t(t,x) + 2tf_x(t,x) + \frac{t^4}{2}f_{xx}(t,x) = 0 \qquad f(T,x) = x^2 = h(x)$$

By Feynman-Kac, the solution is given by

$$f(t, X_t) = E(h(X_T) \mid \mathcal{F}_t)$$

with $X_t$ a stochastic process satisfying the SDE

$$dX_t = 2t dt + t^2 dW_t$$

and hence we have

$$f(t, X_t) = E(X^2_T \mid \mathcal{F}_t)$$

How do I begin to actually compute $f(t, X_t)$? I could write

$$X_T = X_0 + \int_0^T 2s \, \mathrm{d}s + \int_0^T s^2 \, \mathrm{d}W_s$$

and write out $X^2_T$ and take the conditional expectation of that term but this gives alot of messy terms. I am probably missing something simpler, but I am complete lost to what that something might be.

Comment: I think you're approach i ok! Imo it doesn't get to messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need some further clarification. What you want to do is to fix a point $x$ and a time $t$, and consider them as known. Now your solution is 
$$ f(t,x) = E[ h(X_T) | x,t]$$ where 
$X_u$ is a stochastic process satisfying 
\begin{equation} \begin{aligned} &\mathrm{d} X_u = 2u \, \mathrm{d}u + u^2\, \mathrm{d}W_u \quad \text{when} \quad t \leq u \leq T \\ 
&X_t = x \end{aligned} \end{equation}

This gives (similar to your solution, Note $ \int^T_t 2s \, \mathrm{d} s = T^2-t^2.$) 
$$ X_T = x + T^2-t^2 + \int^T_t s^2 \, \mathrm{d}W_s $$

Expanding $X_T^2$ is a good start.

$$ X_T^2 = (x + T^2-t^2)^2 + 2(x+T^2-t^2) \int^T_t s^2 \,\mathrm{d}W_s +
\Big ( \int^T_t s^2 \, \mathrm{d}W_s \Big)^2 $$

Using the Ito isometry and that $ E[\int^T_t s^2 \, \mathrm{d}W_s] = 0$ we get 
$$E[X_T | \mathcal{F}_t] = (x + T^2-t^2)^2 + 
  \int^T_t s^4\, \mathrm{d}s = (x + T^2-t^2)^2 + \frac{T^5-t^5}{5} $$

Comment: Thank you for your help! Isn't it a bit strange that $E[X_T \mid \mathcal{F}_t]$ does not depend on $t$?

Comment: Actually, you fixed $t=0$ and $x=x_0$ and solved $f(0,x_0)$ in that point!

Comment: Also, try to verify that this is really the correct solution